# Windshield Washer Pump connector on 02 Hyundai Accent

Tags: electrical, hyundai

My washer pump does not work on my 02 Accent. I checked the fuse panel under the dash, fuse was ok. I checked the box under the hood, everything is good. Can anyone tell me what the 3 wires that go into the plug for the washer pump are? I know one is orange, one is brown, and one is blue with orange or brown stripe. I have a new factory replacement pump. (98510 25100)  The factory connector was cut off.  I need the pin out to wire correlation. Any help would be great!

Comment: The wiring has been cut off of the current one? or the new one? If it's the new one, you could use the existing one as a pattern?

Comment: Thanks but the original one has been cut off.  I was hoping to find someone that has the same make and model and send me a picture or discription of wht wire goes to what pin on the original connector.